# Data manipulation using r purrr

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr

I have two datasets dat1 and dat2. I would like to pull out rows from dat1 which match the pairs of variables from dat2. var6 can be matched in any of var1, var2, var3, and var4. var7 must be matched with var5.

I would like to come up with a solution using the map functions from the purr package in tidyverse but I'm not sure where to start. Thank you for any help!

```
dat1 <- data.frame(id = c(1:9), 
                   var1 = c("x","x","x","y","y","y","z","z","z"),
                   var2 = c("c","c","c","d","d","d","e","e","e"),
                   var3 = c("f","f","f","g","g","g","h","h","h"),
                   var4 = c("i","i","i","j","j","j","k","k","k"),
                   var5 = c("aa","aa","aa","aa","aa","aa","bb","bb","bb"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat2 <- data.frame(var6 = c("c", "d", "l", "m", "n"),
                   var7 = c("aa", "bb", "aa", "aa","aa"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In this example the result would pull out rows 1, 2, and 3 from dat1 as "c" is matched in var2 and "aa" is matched in var5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need an elementwise comparison, loop through the column 2 to 5 in 'dat1' with `lapply`, then do an elementwisse comparison with 'var6' of 'dat2' using `outer` while doing the same comparison with 'var5', 'var7' columns from 'dat1', 'dat2' respectively, check whether we get both as TRUE (`&`), then take the row wise sum (`rowSums`) to collapse the matrix into a single logical vector and `Reduce` the `list`. of `vector`s into. a single `vector` with `|` i.e. checking whether any of the row elements are TRUE in each of the `vector`s.  It is used for subsetting the rows ('i1')

```
i1 <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(dat1[2:5], function(x) 
     rowSums(outer(x, dat2$var6, `==`) & outer(dat1$var5, dat2$var7, `==`)) > 0 ))
dat1[i1,]
#  id var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
#1  1    x    c    f    i   aa
#2  2    x    c    f    i   aa
#3  3    x    c    f    i   aa
```

---

Or using `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(dat1[2:5], ~ outer(.x, dat2$var6, `==`) &
                 outer(dat1$var5, dat2$var7, `==`)) %>%
   reduce(`+`) %>% 
   rowSums %>%
   as.logical %>%
   magrittr::extract(dat1, ., )
#  id var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
#1  1    x    c    f    i   aa
#2  2    x    c    f    i   aa
#3  3    x    c    f    i   aa
```

Comment: That does work for this case, but what would work as a more general solution where there are some matches for var6 in say var1 and others in var3?

Comment: @JordanHackett. Based on your commeents, `map(dat1[2:5], ~ .x %in% dat2$var6) %>% reduce(`|`)`

Comment: How does that then deal with var5 also matching var7 within the same row?

Comment: @JordanHackett.  Can you show your expeected output.  May be you need `map2(dat2, list(dat1[2:5], dat1[6]), ~  rowSums(.y == .x[col(.y)]) > 0) %>% reduce("&")`

Comment: my expected output would be the first three rows of dat1. This is because the first row of dat2 is "c", "aa" and "c" matches one of var1-4 while "aa" matches var5 within the same row. It is almost like matching the rows between the data sets.

Comment: @JordanHackett. Can you check the input dataset.  i think there would be more matches if I follow your logic

Comment: Sorry I may not be describing this correctly. The input set is correct. This is what I want to check coded in a very lame way: (dat1$var1==dat2$var6[1]|dat1$var2==dat2$var6[1]|dat1$var3==dat2$var6[1]|dat1$var3==dat2$var6[1]) & (dat1$var5==dat2$var7[1]) 

That would check to the first row of dat2. I want to do this except against all rows of dat2

Comment: @JordanHackett. I tried your logic in thiss way `map(dat1[2:5], ~ .x %in% dat2$var6 & dat1$var5 %in% dat2$var7)` i.e. loop through columns 2 through 5 of 'dat'1, check whether it is. in 'var6' and also thee value of 'var5 in var 7 of dat2.  You can check the output.  Now, if I reduce it, it would. still be more ethan 3 rows

Comment: Okay, so you want elementwise comparison?

Comment: I guess so yeah. With var1, 2, 3, 4 being compared to var 6 and var 5 being compared to var 7

Comment: The last code you provided doesn't require the two criteria of the match to be in the same row of dat1, which is what I need

Comment: Yes that works thank you! Sorry I didn't know what to ask for! Do you mind describing what your code and functions you used are doing briefly? Thanks for your time!

Comment: @JordanHackett. i updated with some descriptions.  The `map/reduce` one would be the ssasme as `lapply/Reduce` except for `~ .x` in place of `function(x) x`

Comment: Great thanks a lot! I appreciate the explanation! Was actually a much harder problem for me than it appeared on the surface.